# How to continue to execute the C++ code after gnuplot was called?

Tags: c++, gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I am using gcc as a compiler and gnuplot-iostream.h as a stream to combine C++ code and the gnuplot features.

What I am doing:

I try to make a fit of the data via gnuplot and extract the final fit parameters from the generated fit.log file for further processing.

What's the problem:

When executing the code like this

```
std::cout << "Starting to fit" << std::endl;
if (bStartFit == true)
{
    // gp << doing stuf here;
    std::cout << "Test end" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Fit is done" << std::endl;
```

the output will be:

```
Starting to fit
Fit is done
Test end
//gnuplot stuff
```

My question is: how to force the code execute gnuplot stuff exactly when needed, and after proceed with the C++ code. For example:

- write intro message;
- plot the sin(x) function (as fast example);
- wait until the gnuplot is closed;
- write exiting message or do what ever AFTER the gnuplot is done.

thank you,
P

EDIT:

```
  std::string filename = "fit.log";
  if (bStartFit == true)
  {
    // Using Gnuplot for the data fit (command are parsed as the strings):
    // 1. define the fit function.
    gp << "f(x) = imfpZP * x**(-b) + c * x**(d) + g * x**(h) \n";
    // 2. fit parameters first assumption.
    gp << "b = 1.1; c = 0.5; d = 1.0; g = 2.0; h = 0.1 \n";
    // 3. fit range.
    gp << "fit [50:10000] f(x) 'agn.iimfp' via b,c,d,g,h \n";
    // 4. set the logarithmic scale.
    gp << "set logscale \n";
    // 5. plot the fitted data.
    gp << "plot 'agn.iimfp' w l lw 2 tit 'orig', f(x) w l lw 2 tit 'fit' \n";

    std::cout << "Fit was successful" << std::endl;
  }

  // Opening the generated fit.log file to store the fit parameters:
  std::ifstream inFIT(filename.c_str());
  if (inFIT.is_open())
  {
    std::cout << "FIT log is opened" << std::endl;

    std::string line;
    int lineCounter = 0;
    while (std::getline(inFIT, line))
    {
      lineCounter++;
    }
    std::cout << "Total lines: " << lineCounter << std::endl;

    // Getting the five lines with fit parameters from the fit.log:
    std::fstream& GoToLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int lineNumber);
    std::fstream file(filename.c_str());


    GoToLine(file, lineCounter - 15);
    std::string b_Line;
    std::getline(file, b_Line);
    std::cout << b_Line << std::endl;
    std::istringstream sb(b_Line);
    std::string tempStr;
    char tempChar;
    sb >> tempStr >> tempChar  >> b
    // similar code to get another 4 lines
```

;

Comment: What do you mean _"gnuplot stuff"_?? How do you call gnuplot?

Comment: I am not sure at all that using *gnuplot iostream* fits your needs.

Comment: by "gnuplot stuff" I mean the gnuplot header, if I use "fit" command I will get a fitting iterations here as well, and the plot itself will be the last thing that is produced.

Comment: I feel that `gnuplot` is relevant to you, but not the *gnuplot iostream*

Comment: I call it via: `gp << "plot f(x) w l lw 3 tit 'fit function'  \n"`. In a similar way to define that f(x) function before and fit it to the data from file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is operating system specific. I am guessing you are on Linux (or at least on some [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) OS). Then you really should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). And using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) could be helpful to understand what is happening.

You could use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), but you probably should explicitly use [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (they are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) like [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), etc. And very probably have some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (e.g. around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)).

BTW, you should be aware that input output is [buffered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), and you probably want to **be sure that your *gnuplot stream* is regularly flushed** (so use `std::endl` or `std::flush` appropriately on it). Writing a `\n` is not enough! You probably should code at least

```
gp << "plot 'agn.iimfp' w l lw 2 tit 'orig', f(x) w l lw 2 tit 'fit' " 
   << std::endl;
```

<sup>(I have replaced some `\n` inside a string with an explicit use of [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl))</sup>

I don't know much about [*gnuplot stream*](http://stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) (I'm guessing it is a bit like some specialized `popen` but using C++ streams), but I guess that you should the gnuplot `print` or `printerr` command to communicate to your calling program the fact that a given curve has been plotted. (But then you need a genuine event loop, and you are defining a bidirectional protocol between `gnuplot` and your program.).

Perhaps [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) might be relevant, because they provide some notion of event loop and processes. Perhaps you might have several threads (one managing `gnuplot` and the other for the rest), but then you have synchronization issues.

<sup>(I don't understand enough what your program is supposed to do, and how you have coded it, so it is a blind guess; I feel your question is very unclear)</sup>

Read more about [Inter-Process Communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: Hey, I work on Linux machine, that's true, but I would like not to use system specific calls if possible. I am new to this gnuplot-iostream and faced such problem which I can solve by writing two separate programs, but first I would like to figure out maybe there is a way to solve it within the one code.

Comment: But your question does not show enough code and is still unclear. I believe you are misunderstanding something essential. Perhaps the issues are not where you believe they are.

Comment: By using Qt I will need to write a fitting function by myself. In my work I need to use the gnuplot in order to get the fitting parameters and use them later on within the C++ code and the gnuplot as well. So, it is not a good alternative for me

Comment: I will add more code right now in the main question

Comment: But then it looks like you need some event loop, and some protocol from gnuplot to your application. My feeling is that you need to have some event loop and understand multiplexing syscalls à la `poll`. Or you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I have a file with data, I fit that data with gnuplot, I read the fit.log file to get the final fit parameters and proceed with them within C++ code. The problem is that C++ code right now executes BEFORE the gnuplot is called even if it states in the code before. I don't know to loop it properly, I've tried already

Comment: You really need to learn more about Linux programming. And we cannot explain that in an answer. I have given useful references.

Comment: Why did you accept my answer (what was right in it)? I just made a set of guesses about your code, that you did not describe enough.

Comment: I have checked the `std::endl` statement and now it works properly... I am curious why in this case an examples of gnuplot-iostream are not showing such things (or they are not needed for the simple programs?) Ah, Exaple 2 shows it... gosh..

Comment: Because buffering is not specific to *gnuplot-iostream*. They don't need to document that. But you need to read a lot more about Linux programming.

Comment: Yes, I will, thank you for your help

Comment: That is the sad fact about programming. Even if you are doing it only for e.g. a PhD in physics, you need to learn a lot more about programming. See http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: In fact I am doing it for my PhD, I will follow you advice, thank you